# Lighttpd load balancing configuration

Tags: configuration, localhost, port, load-balancing, lighttpd

I am configuring a Load balancer in Play Framework using Lighttpd **1.4.30**.

I have given entries in  lighttpd-inc.conf as below.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "http://10.74.9.109:9020" {
proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" =>
( ( "host" => "10.74.9.109", "port" => 9020 ) ) )
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "http://10.74.9.109:80" {
    proxy.balance = "round-robin" proxy.server = ( "/" => ( 
          ( "host" => "10.74.9.109", "port" => 9020 ), 
          ( "host" => "10.74.9.109", "port" => 9030 ) ) 
    )
}
```

My play application is running fine on ports 9020, 9030.

But when I tried `http://localhost:80` my load balancer should transfer the request to any of these ports which is not happening. I am getting only Lighttpd test page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lighttpd Reverse Proxy Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352283/lighttpd-reverse-proxy-settings)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly make sure you have mod_proxy in your `server.modules` array.

I think using `$HTTP["host"]` is the problem here. You should use `$SERVER["socket"]` like so:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":9020" {
    proxy.server = (
        "/" => (
            (
                "host" => "10.74.9.109",
                "port" => 9020
            )
        )
    )
}

$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    proxy.server = (
        "/" => ( 
              ( "host" => "10.74.9.109", "port" => 9020 ), 
              ( "host" => "10.74.9.109", "port" => 9030 )
        ) 
    )
}
```